# references for optimal computation under memory constraint?

Tags: computability, space-bounded

Can someone help me find some references for finding good execution schedule given memory constraint? Assuming computation graph is simple in some sense (ie, small tree-width)

There is this reference about the problem being hard in general: "Inapproximability of Treewidth, One-Shot Pebbling, and Related Layout Problems", https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4910, but I'm interested in a practical algorithm